# Displaying the timezone properly in XSLT

Tags: date, datetime, xslt

Was using the below tag for displaying the timezone which was working fine until now when the daylight saving has happened and as our server is in UK displaying the time as `01/04/2015 03:43:00 PM + 0100`, we would also like to have the timezone displayed, please advice.

Tag Used Previously:

```
date:format-date(date:date-time(), 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a Z')
```

Regards
Arvind

Comment: Sorry, but it's not clear what your question is.  You say "we would ... like to have the timezone displayed".  Does the string "+0100" not count as a timezone for your purposes?  Technically, it's a time offset (from UTC) and not a 'time zone' (region defined by civil law which specifies a given offset from UTC), and it does not distinguish between British Summer Time and European winter time, but it serves the same purposes and most people call it a timezone.  What is it you want and do not have?

Answer (score 0):

If by "properly" you mean you want it displayed as "BST" (for British Summer Time) then there isn't actually enough information in the date/time value to do this - a time-zone offset of +1 occurs in many different timezones near the Greenwich meridian.

You're using the `EXSLT` library for formatting dates and times. This is based on Java's `SimpleDateFormat` class, so you could try your luck with the timezone designator `z` instead of `Z`.

Alternatively, if you've got access to XSLT 2.0, you can use the `format-dateTime()` function. This suffers from the same problem (the dateTime value only stores an offset, which doesn't actually tell you the name of the timezone). But you can give the processor a clue by setting the 5th argument of `format-dateTime()` to "Europe/London", in which case it might be able to work it out.